# Turn off coloured change tracking areas in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 now shows if content is edited or new on the left side of the text editor:
[image]

I think this used to be in the scrollbar and could be turned off there. Now I don't see it in scrollbar options and can find nothing on google about turning it off.

Right clicking on it does nothing, I've looked around in Options but can see nothing.

How do I turn this off?

thx

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor > General, "Track changes" checkbox.

Comment: Awesome thanks, feel free to make this an answer so the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Visual a Visual Studio Project go to : Tools/Option/Text Editor/ General And turn Off the Flag on 'Track Changes' checkbox.[image]